# Including a Library without using CMake

Tags: c++, include

I'm looking to include a library ([linked here](http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php)) in C++. I don't want to use CMake if I don't have to, so what is the way to just do `include "libstemmer.h` and have it work? What do I have to build first?

Comment: What compiler and platform are you using?  You'll need to link to the library somehow, be it dynamic or static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a library without linking to the library

unless the library is header only, in which case just including the header will work.

**edit**
The download includes c files and a makefile - you can either run the make file, or include the c files directly in your project.

Comment: Alright. It's not header only, so how do I link to it? Something like -l libstemmer, or do I have to build it first? If so, what do I use when I build it?

Comment: You need to build the library if your OS does not provide it for you. If there is a Makefile. You should be able to use that without CMake and the usual make then make install.

Comment: So once I build it, how do I link it?